# Player constantly spinning when pressing Caps Lock

Tags: battlefield-4, keyboard

I've just purchased Battlefield 4. I spent half a day configuring my controls and fine-tuning everything. For some annoying reason whenever I hit Caps Lock, my character spins vastly and I can't stop it.

I don't have anything plugged to my laptop except for the mouse, headset and internet.

I can resolve this issue by ALT-tabbing out and in the game, but the problem keeps coming back.

Any idea how this can be prevented or solved? It's really annoying, especially since I use Shift a lot and sometimes accidently hit Caps.

I would even accept it if for the time playing, it would be possible to disable caps.

Answer (score 1):

First, check your ease of access settings in control panel, and make sure it matches [this picture.](http://i1180.photobucket.com/albums/x404/CCCaesar/Wndwkybrdsht.png~original)

Look at the image link I posted and make sure yours matches it's settings.

Control Panel >> Easy of Access Center >> Make the Keyboard easier to use`

Uncheck everything.

One more thing you can try. 
Go to your Documents Folder > Battlefield 4 > Settings and rename the file called `PROFSAVE_profile` to `PROFSAVE_profile.old`

Restart your PC and start the game back up. It might be necessary to run the Repair Game option in Origin, but I doubt it.